# Querying sys.master_files over a linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, metadata

Querying sys.master_files through a linked server, I get no results.

Why? How do I work around this issue?

Comment: You may want to provide a little bit more details before your question is closed. What do you mean by "no results", for example?

Comment: No results means the number of returned rows was zero. There are no more details to provide and I can't see a good reason to close since others understood the problem immediately and have been able to point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This approach works fine for me:

```
SELECT * FROM [linked_server_name].master.sys.master_files;
```

What you need to be sure of is that the linked server is running in the context of a user who has enough privileges to see the contents of the DMV. You can check who you're executing as using:

```
EXEC [linked server name].master.sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT SUSER_SNAME(),
   ORIGINAL_LOGIN();';
```

Comment: your hint seems to lead into the right direction. It's a matter of permission of the Linked Server User context. TY. I can't figure out the permission I have to add. BTW, the view exists in every db, so it looks like it's not required to use the master db. I want to prevent setting permissions on single objects if not really required. Is there a db role suitable for this?

Comment: I applied USE master; GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO SqlDbaController 
GO 
and this made it work. TY.